# python3 extract :) symbol from string

Tags: python, nlp, emoji, emoticons

I found all kinds of tools for pasring emoji and emoticons, but none of them are working for extracting a simple ":)" out of a string:

```
from emot.emo_unicode import UNICODE_EMO, EMOTICONS
":)" in EMOTICONS
>>>False
```

I've tried using replace to convert all ":)" to ':‑\)' and it still doesn't work. It seems simple, but I cannot find any examples on the interwebs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

s = 'Pull the emoticon :):) out ):'
(news, count) = re.subn(r'(\s*:\)\s*)', ' ', s)
# 'Pull the emoticon out ):'

print('new string', news)
print('count', count)
```

Comment: How about if I want to pull them out and keep them (aka pop)? :)

Comment: Hey @SummerEla, I edited my answer to also count them and make the spaces before and after the smilies optional